# Control for multiple text values in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a custom data model that has a few fields similar to this:

```
<property name="my:Property1">
    <title>Property1</title>
    <type>d:text</type>
    <multiple>true</multiple>
</property>
```

The problem is that it is rendered as a single textbox in Share. 
Is there any control I can use within a form to manage a text property that allow multiple values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the OOTB one accepts and renders it as a comma separated values. It should be fairly straightforward to construct a custom one that fits your need though.

There is an open issue for this at Alfresco (cast a vote on it :))

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-3144

Comment: I started to construct a custom template to add/remove properties, but I have run into problem when I wanted to save values containing a comma. My value should be stored as a single entry "Name1, Address1", but it is stored as two separate values ["Name1", "Address1"]. Do you have any suggestions how to handle this? Thank you!

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve one nice solution that I like to use is to use a regular d:text property (that is not multiple=true) and save it as a json-string. The custom-template then handles the serialization/deserialization stuff.

Comment: It's a very good solution, but unfortunately, in that case I would have to change a content model. I can't do this, because that property is used in many functionalities that my clients are already using in Alfresco Explorer. I have an idea to change my property to use some other sign instead of "," and change that in every place in repository where I have saved that property. Do you have, maybe, some better idea to solve that problem not changing content model?

Comment: Well, I would escape the commas that comes from user input. A java example:

   `StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   for (int i = 0; i < userName.length(); i++)
   {
     char c = userName.charAt(i);
     if (c == ',')
     {
       sb.append('\\');
     }
     sb.append(c);`
   }
   return sb.toString();

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this recently 2/7/2015 and had the same issue of needing to create a table or a property value that you can add or delete records too. I stumbled upon this github repository https://github.com/msvoren/alfresco-datatable-property
but i noticed that it had some errors in the javascript from being several years old. I have since updated the javascript to work with alfresco community 5.0.c

[Git Hub Repo](https://github.com/craigNelson1/alfresco-datatable-property)